# Two fdisks seeing different MBRs on same external drive (OpenBSD 4.2/5.5)

Tags: openbsd, fdisk, mbr

I'm trying to use an external USB hard drive to copy data between a legacy production OpenBSD 4.2 system (on a slow, fragile network — that's not an option) and a new OpenBSD 5.5 box, and I'm running into a freaky wall while trying to get the drive formatted.  Neither box will recognize the MBR written by the other machine.

At this point, I have used `fdisk -i` on both machines to reinitialize the MBR, using each OS' default MBR template.

On the transfer system:

```
xfer# fdisk sd1
Disk: sd1       geometry: 30400/255/63 [488378645 4096-byte Sectors]
Offset: 0       Signature: 0xAA55
            Starting         Ending         LBA Info:
 #: id      C   H   S -      C   H   S [       start:        size ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0: 00      0   0   0 -      0   0   0 [           0:           0 ] unused      
 1: 00      0   0   0 -      0   0   0 [           0:           0 ] unused      
 2: 00      0   0   0 -      0   0   0 [           0:           0 ] unused      
*3: A6      0   1   1 -  30399 254  63 [          63:   488375937 ] OpenBSD
```

On the production system (which already has another drive at sd1):

```
prod# fdisk sd2
Disk: sd2       geometry: 30400/255/63 [488378645 4096-byte Sectors]
Offset: 0       Signature: 0xAA55
          Starting         Ending        LBA Info:
 #: id      C   H  S -      C   H  S [       start:        size ]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0: 00      0   0  0 -      0   0  0 [           0:           0 ] unused      
 1: 00      0   0  0 -      0   0  0 [           0:           0 ] unused      
 2: 00      0   0  0 -      0   0  0 [           0:           0 ] unused      
*3: A6      0   1  2 -  30399 254 63 [          64:   488375936 ] OpenBSD
```

I used disklabel on both the production and transfer machines; neither will see each other's partition table, and if I swap the drive back and forth to each machine in turn, each of them continues to see its own copy of the disklabel, even after using `disklabel -c` on both sides to sync from disk. (I'm assuming that's because the MBR partitions start at different sectors.)

But I'm mightily confused.  I thought the whole point of an MBR was to be, well, *master*?  Why aren't the two machines in agreement about the MBR of the drive, and what can I do to get them seeing the same partition table?

Edit: Further research into other disk partitioning schemes has not clarified anything, except to reaffirm that this is an MBR problem.  The [OpenBSD disk setup page](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#Boot386) mentions the Partition Boot Record, but that's located in the OpenBSD partition of the MBR so it won't affect what fdisk sees.  And OpenBSD still, as of 2014, doesn't have support for GUID Partition Tables.  [This FAQ answer](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#blankfdisk) seems related, but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: What is the version of `fdisk` on each machine?

Comment: @eyoung100 I'm having a surprising amount of difficulty finding that out. fdisk doesn't support the `--version` or `-v` flags, and it comes with the OS so `pkg_info` doesn't list it.  Both should be the ones originally installed with the OS (OpenBSD 4.2 and 5.5).

Comment: @eyoung100 [This page](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/sbin/fdisk/Makefile) suggests that OpenBSD 4.2 ships with fdisk 1.35 and 5.5 ships with fdisk 1.39, but I don't know if that's the real version number.

Comment: Here's my hunch... We need to rule out a version conflict as the cause of the issue.  You need to put the same versions of fdisk on both machines, and compare the outputs again.

Comment: Did you zero out the first 1k of the drive before rerunning fdisk and then disklabel on either machine? (`dd if=/dev/zero ...`)